# What's the right terminal to use to see these characters?

Tags: linux, vim, docker, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to get the vim-bundle Docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/jare/vim-bundle/) to work. It works, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong with regard to my terminal setup.

I'm running Linux Mint, and my terminal emulator is Gnome Terminal 3.18.3

My `TERM` environment variable is set to `xterm-256color`.

Any ideas what I need to do to get the crispness as seen in the screenshot on the Docker Hub link above? A different terminal emulator? Different configuration for vim-bundle?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vim plugin displaying the status bar is vim-airline:
https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline

According to its documentation, what I'm not seeing are the fonts from the powerline package, a previous Vim statusbar plugin that is no longer maintained.

The documentation page gives a simple fix.  Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
```

... and that makes it look much nicer.  No terminal software changes or terminal variable changes are needed, and at least in my case, no additional software needed to be installed.